# Why can't I use the generic type of class as the method parameter type?

Tags: dart

here is what I want to try to achieve

```dart
@freezed
class Normalized<T extends IEntity> with _$Normalized<T> {
  const factory Normalized({
    required Map<ID, T> byId,
    required List<ID> ids,
  }) = _Normalized;

  factory Normalized.empty() => const Normalized(
        ids: [],
        byId: {},
      );

  const Normalized._();

  Normalized<T> add(T data) {
    final tempById = {...byId, data.id: data};

    return copyWith(
      byId: tempById,
      ids: ids.contains(data.id) ? ids : [...ids, data.id],
    );
  }

  /// type 'List<T>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Never>' of 'data'
  Normalized<T> mergeList(List<T> data) {
    final ids = [...this.ids];
    final byId = {...this.byId};

    for (T x in data) {
      byId[x.id] = x;
      if (!ids.contains(x.id)) {
        ids.add(x.id);
      }
    }

    return copyWith(byId: byId, ids: ids);
  }
```

---

When I call add or mergeList T is recognized as Never。

> ```
> Error:  type 'List<ParamKey>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Never>' of 'data'
> ```

```dart
    Normalized<ParamKey> preParamKeys = state.paramKeys;

    final res = await ref.read(productsRepositoryProvider).fetchOneProduct(id);
    
    ///  type 'List<ParamKey>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Never>' of 'data'
    preParamKeys.mergeList(res.paramKeys);
```

the param type of the method should be recognized as T

Update: It seems that the type parameter is useless, runtimeType is never.

1. Define ProductsState type,  please focus on factory empty

```dart
@freezed
class ProductsState with _$ProductsState {
  const factory ProductsState({
    required Normalized<Product> products,
    required Normalized<ParamKey> paramKeys,
    required Normalized<ParamValue> paramValues,
    required Normalized<ProductVariant> variants,
    required Map<ID, PricingSchema> pricingSchemas,
    required AsyncStatus status,
  }) = _ProductsState;

  factory ProductsState.empty() => ProductsState(
        products: Normalized<Product>.empty(),
        paramKeys: Normalized<ParamKey>.empty(),
        paramValues: Normalized<ParamValue>.empty(),
        variants: Normalized.empty(),
        pricingSchemas: <ID, PricingSchema>{},
        status: const AsyncStatus.idle(),
      );
}
```

2. create an empty ProductsState and print it's runtypeTime;

```dart
main() {
    final x = ProductsState.empty();
    print("build: ${x.paramKeys.runtimeType}"); /// -> will print "_$NormalizedImpl<Never>"
}
```

the print result of the runtime type is Never.
It looks like the generic type parameter is not working.

update: I found the problem. I need to pass the type parameter T to the return value of Normalized.empty, but if I do this, the return value cannot be const.

```dart
  factory Normalized.empty() => Normalized<T>(
     ids: <ID>[],
     byId: <ID, T>{},
  );
```

Comment: It's not clear where `List<Never>` is coming from.  It's not possible for `T` to be `Never` when calling `preParamKeys.mergeList(...)` since `preParamKeys` was already declared with `T` as  `ParamKey`.  Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can demonstrate the problem you're encountering.  The process of creating such an example often can provide you with insight into the cause (and possibly the solution).

Comment: hi  thanks @jamesdlin, i updated the description and added an example of print the runtimeType

Comment: @jamesdlin The Normalized.empty also need a generic type param T,  but if type parameter added the return value can not as const data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Never` most likely comes from

```dart
factory Normalized.empty() => const Normalized(
        ids: [],
        byId: {},
      );
```

There is no type argument to `Normalized`, and it's inside a `const`, so it chooses the only type which will make the return value valid for any binding of `T`, which is never. That's generally what `const` does with generic object creation expressions.

If you do `Normalized<T>.empty().merge(Normalized<T>())`, you will get this error.

If you remove the `const` from the `empty` constructor, it should work.

The underlying problem is that `<T>` occurs contravariantly in the method signature.
Even doing a

```dart
Normalized<num> n = Normalized<int>();
n.merge(Normalized<num>());
```

will throw. The `Normalized.empty()` is just an example that will throw for any non-`Normalized<Never>`-typed argument.

The easiest solution is to make the `empty` result non-constant, so it remembers the type that the creator wanted.

A second step could be caching the empty object per requested type:

```dart
  factory Normalized.empty() => (_cache[T] ??= Normalized<T>(
      ids: [], byId: {})) as Normalized<T>;
  static Map<Type, Normalized> _cache = {};
```

I don't think there is any way to make this work with a constant `empty` object. It will necessarily have type `Normalized<Never>`,
and the method `add` has type `Normalized<T> Function(T)`, which means the `const` object *must* return a `Normalized<Never>`. There is no way to make that work with the actual value being added. Even if we create a new class for the constant, one that allows any `IEntity` as argument, it still cannot return any other type.

Comment: Yes. Is there any way to preserve "const"?

Comment: I'd say "no" in this case. Updated answer with explanation. The API simply doesn't allow a single constant to implement it for all possible types for `T`.